# How do I configure logback to gzip my logs automatically?

Tags: configuration, gzip, logback

i am using logback in my java web appliaction. here's my "logback.xml" file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">

    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="/home/ying/.jetty_logs/vehicle" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}[%L] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LAST" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/last.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>last.%d{yyyy-MM}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>24</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date:%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.shiro" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN" />

    <logger name="ying.car.interceptor.AutoLoginInterceptor" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="LAST" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="ying.car.controller.LoginController" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="LAST" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="ying.car.controller.LogoutController" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="LAST" />
    </logger>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

today is june 1st 2013, all my old logs are overwrited and no *.gz created. 
somebody help me, please.

Comment: set <configuration debug="true"> and see what logback tells you.

Answer (score 48):

Try to do like this, Hope it will work for you.

```xml
<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${LOGDIR}/filename.log</File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <FileNamePattern>${LOGDIR}/file.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
        </FileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 10MB -->
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The above code will compress your file on the day basis or If the log file size exceeds 10MB.

Note : I have added "%i" in filePattern, It will iterate your file name as file1,file2 etc.

Comment: Shorter answer : fileNamePattern - (...) Note that file compression is also specified via this property. For example, fileNamePattern set to MyLogFile%i.log.zip means that archived files must be compressed using the zip format; gz format is also supported. source : https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: Gist: The fileNamePattern must include the full path, otherwise the rolling files get saved at the root of the classPath

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `<cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>` so that the rollover happens on next startup, as if it wasn't running at the time of rollover it wouldn't have happened.